What Is This Hidden Folders With Random Numbers On My Phone? How Do I Remove It?
I have a xiaomi phone, poco F4, with android 13, miui version 14.0.11.
this random folders have random number on it, it is an empty folder, no files inside.
this folders keep bothering me, i have some question about this folders.
is this folders a virus / malware?
is it created by android system?
or is it created by app that i've installed?
i don't know the way to detect this folders is created by what app, is there any way to know?
i've tried to remove this folder about 3 times, and the folders keeps reappearing.
if anyone know something about this issue, please help me.
thanks.
this hidden folders is visible from my computer / my device file manager.



Just a guess: have you rebooted the phone directly before connecting it to the computer? The file-names look a bit like the encrypted file-names Android uses internally for storing your user content in an encrypted way. Normally you don't see these file-names as Android automatically decrypts them.
